# React Native asyncStorage undefined error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, asyncstorage

React Native also returns async storage as undefined. I didn't understand what caused the problem. I tried it in Android Studio and on my own device, and I'm getting the same error.
I have given the code that returns the error below.

```
try {
      const contactData = (await AsyncStorage.getItem('contact_data')) || '[]'
      if (!contactData) return []
      return JSON.parse(contactData)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error getContactData', e)
    }
```

I have shared the link of the error image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8n8B.png)

The screen stays on the white screen because the result is not returned.

I need help on why it is returning undefined. It works on ios device but android also gives an error

Comment: can you show the import for async storage

Comment: I'm importing as import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

Comment: Did you try storing a word and retrieving it in android?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing async (await should be used with async)

Comment: I already use it with await when calling.
const contacts = await ContactDataList.getContactData()

Comment: You are missing async